# Java: making int and boolean comparable in "if" statements

Tags: java, boolean

Is it possible to have a statement such as...

```
     if(delco == 1 && heavy < 5)
         System.out.println("The total cost of your delivery is: $" + OPT_ONE);
     if(delco == 1 && heavy >= 5 && heavy <= 20)
        System.out.println("The total cost of your delivery is: $" + OPT_TWO);
```

...that also applies boolean logic to express an output? Something like this...

```
  boolean overnight;

     if(delco == 1 && heavy < 5) && (overnightShip == YES)
         System.out.println("The total cost of your delivery is: $" + OPT_ONE + OVERNIGHT);
     if(delco == 1 && heavy >= 5 && heavy <= 20) && (overnightShip == NO)
        System.out.println("The total cost of your delivery is: $" + OPT_TWO);
```

I have tried a few variations of this code and the error I'm receiving states that they are incomparable types. How do I go about making them comparable?

Comment: What are the types of `overnightShip`, `YES`, and `NO`?  Also, includes parentheses around the entire `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed some parentheses, because your logic seems OK. It should be, e.g.:

```
if ( (delco == 1 && heavy < 5) && (overnightShip == YES) )
    ...
```

Note the outer parentheses.

Also that assumes that you've defined `YES` to be a boolean constant equal to `true`, and that is redundant, so:

```
if ( (delco == 1 && heavy < 5) && (overnightShip) )
    ...
```

And in this case, those parentheses are redundant as well, and the whole thing simplifies to:

```
if ( delco == 1 && heavy < 5 && overnightShip )
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the boolean on its own:

```
if (delco == 1 && heavy < 5 && overnightShip)
```

Comparing a boolean "flag" variable with a boolean constant is poor style - always prefer testing the boolean as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean types in Java have the values:

```
true
false
```

Not:

```
YES
NO
```

unless you have defined these constants yourself somewhere

So your code should look like:

```
(overnightShip == true)
(overnightShip == false)
```

or even:

```
(overnightShip)    // true
(! overnightShip)  // false
```